# Splitting worksheet into separate data sets and saving each in new template file

Tags: excel, vba

This question is a follow-up to:
[Saving specific named worksheets in workbook based on criteria using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38253420/saving-specific-named-worksheets-in-workbook-based-on-criteria-using-vba/38257780#38257780)

What I want to do is take a source workbook, split the workbook (which has just one sheet) up by employee ID number (One Column's Data), then open a template file and save each template file under the name of the employee (Another Column's Data). The goal is to automatically "run" the template process for each employee from a giant aggregate data block.

```
Sub SplitBook(ExternalFilePath As String, Optional sPassword As String)

    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim wb As Workbook, wbSource As Workbook
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Dim Secured

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set wbSource = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=ExternalFilePath,       ReadOnly:=True, password:=sPassword)

    Dim lr As Long

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim vcol, i As Integer
    Dim icol As Long
    Dim myarr As Variant
    Dim title As String
    Dim titlerow As Integer

    vcol = 4
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")


    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
    title = "A1:Z1"
    titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
    icol = ws.Columns.Count
    ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"

    For i = 2 To lr
        On Error Resume Next
        If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
            ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
        End If
    Next

    myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
    ws.Columns(icol).Clear

    For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
        ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
        If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
            Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
            wb.SaveAs Filename:=FilePath, _
                FileFormat:=xlExcel8, password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
                ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False

            Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
        Else
            Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        End If
        ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
        Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        wb = Nothing
    Next

    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    ws.Activate
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True    
End Sub
```

I need to change the getNewFilePath function to name files as *name of template* + name of the Employee + ".xls"

```
Function getNewFilePath(ws As Workbook, i As Integer) As String

        nameCol = ws.Cells(i, 4).Value

        If Len(Trim(ws.Cells(i, 4).Value)) = 0 Then Exit Function

        s = Split(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, ".xls", 2) & nameCol

        If Err.Number = 0 Then getNewFilePath = s & ".xls"
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Comment: What getFilename method are you referring to? Is the function listed above the one you're trying - what does it print out and how does it compare tou what you want?

Comment: I have the getFileName *function* as the code above describes, the code isn't working the way I want it to of course.

Comment: Do you mean "getNewFilePath" listed above?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean

Comment: Can you update your question with an example of what you would expect from the function - and what you're getting now? That will make it easy for us to provide the correct code. Also explaing the relatiobship between the first set of code and the function. It doesn't appear to be used anywhere in your code.